# C++ Check diagonally from 2d array

Tags: c++

Beginner at c++ here.

```
for (int z = 0; z < arraysize; z++) {

    if (generated[z][0] == generated[z][1] && generated[z][1] == generated[z][2]) {
        wins++;
    }

    if (generated[0][z] == generated[1][z] && generated[1][z] == generated[2][z]) {
        wins++;
    }
```

As you can see it checks for the horizontal lines. I would like to check wether or not there are 3 in a row diagonally. If there is, the wins variable should add one. Any ideas?

Comment: (Not an answer) Using `arraysize` is nice, but you are countering that by using `2` in the code itself... Consider using a loop inside as well; this is close to hardcoding to a fixed size.

Comment: @Peter, What is your arraysize?

Comment: @AerofoilKite const int = 3;

Comment: @Peter, :). Then i'm right

Comment: @AerofoilKite Yes! You've been very helpful. Big thank you! =)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `z` as the index for both extents instead of just one.

```
for (int z = 0; z < arraysize; z++)
{
    if (generated[z][z] == generated[0][0])
    {
        //... handle it
    }
    if (generated[arraysize - z - 1][z] == generated[arraysize - 1][0])
    {
        //... handle it
    }

}
```

Unfortunately this will only get you so far. The current logic in your code is not going to work as you expect. The problem is that it keeps a cumulative count of matches across all lines both horizontally and vertically. If you have several partial matches you could end up with a an incorrect `win` value. You can avoid this problem by adding a couple of additional loops to check the contents of each the vertical and horizontal lines as you perform your scan. This will require a couple of additional flags to be added as well to keep track of whether there is a win in either direction. The following example should provide you with a much more flexible set of checks that are flexible and can be used for any size array.

```
bool hwin = false;
bool vwin = false;
int d1wins = 0;
int d2wins = 0;
for (int z = 0; z < arraysize; z++)
{
    int hwins = 0;
    int vwins = 0;

    //  Check horizontal line
    for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; ++i)
    {
        if (generated[i][z] == generated[0][z])
        {
            hwins++;
        }
    }
    hwin = hwin || hwins == arraysize;

    //  Check vertical line
    for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; ++i)
    {
        if (generated[z][i] == generated[z][0])
        {
            vwins++;
        }
    }
    vwin = vwin || vwins == arraysize;

    //  Check diagonal
    if (generated[z][z] == generated[0][0])
    {
        d1wins++;
    }

    //  Check diagonal
    if (generated[arraysize - z - 1][z] == generated[arraysize - 1][0])
    {
        d2wins++;
    }
}

bool dwin = d1wins == arraysize || d2wins == arraysize;
```

Comment: Arraysize is 3. I think he is trying Tic-tac-toe. And he checks horizontal and vertical only for size 3. So you should not use loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very appreciated. Trying to do a slot machine counting diagonals and horizontals

Comment: @Peter Then you'll definitely want to make sure that your code is adjustable between the number of rows available on each row. 3x3 is one configuration but 5x3 and 5x4 are more common these days. this required a bit more logic than you're ready for given your current code.

Answer (score 1):

From two if condition, you used, I think you are trying something like 3*3 Tic-tac-toe.

So, if your arraysize is 3, you can't use following checking in your loop:

```
if (generated[z][z] == generated[z+1][z+1] && generated[z+1][z+1] == generated[z+2][z+2])
{
    wins++;
}
```

z+2 and z+1 will cross the array limit.

---

So you can check it outside of your loop:

```
generated[0][0] == generated[1][1] && generated[1][1] == generated[2][2]
generated[0][2] == generated[1][1] && generated[1][1] == generated[2][0]
```

Comment: There is no indication the size of the array is fixed or if it is that the dimensions are the ones used in your solution.

Comment: Ofcourse not. But in both of his 'if' condition, he just use 3*3 size array to check. Thats why, its better to be 3*3 array.. Tnx for downvote